# Can I access scoped variables from outside the scope?

Tags: javascript, scope

Is there any way to access scoped variables from outside the scope?

For example how to edit `count` from outside of this function:

```
var counter = (function(){
    var count = 0;
    return function () {
        return ++count;
    };
})();
```

Comment: That is not the same question at all @Jhawins

Comment: How is it not the same?

Comment: Because the question **and** answer have nothing to do with this question. Just the question title, which does not mean anything @paqogomez

Answer (score 4):

It is not currently possible (nor do I think it will **ever** be possible) to access a local variable from outside the scope.

That is the whole idea.

What you *can* do is change the return of the function to return an object so that you can increase and decrease the `count` variable:

```
function counterObject = (function(){
    var count = 0;
    return {
       up: function(){ return ++count; },    
       down: function(){ return --count; }      
    };
})();

counterObject.up(); // 1
counterObject.up(); // 2
counterObject.up(); // 3
counterObject.down(); // 2
counterObject.up(); // 3
```

But aside from doing the above there is no *real* access to the local scoped variable.

Comment: `__parent__` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Parent

Comment: If you're going to do something like this it should be a community wiki, not a simple Q/A because you are not and never will be the sole authority on something like this, and your answer will need to be molded into perfection by the community.

Comment: You **are** allowed to answer your own question on the Stack Exchange. I am not claiming any authority.

Comment: @JHa  I'm not an expert on the subject matter of this specific Q&A, but [answering your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is allowed, and even encouraged, here.

Comment: What you've done here is implement the Module pattern as described http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript  This allows the usage of public and private members of objects and encapsulation in Javascript.